# Alternate to reduce to send live stats (of reduce)

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a silly question, but couldn't know the cause:

```
import akka.{Done, NotUsed}
import akka.actor.Status.Success
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, RunnableGraph, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}

import scala.concurrent.Future


object Generic {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
    implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

    val sink: Sink[Any, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach(x => println("Ans =====> " + x))

    val counts = Flow[String]
      .mapConcat(x => x.split("\\s").toList)
      .filter(!_.isEmpty)
      .groupBy(Int.MaxValue, identity)
      .map(x => x -> 1)
      .reduce((l, r) => (l._1, l._2 + r._2))
      .mergeSubstreams

    val fold: Flow[String, Int, NotUsed] = Flow[String].map(x => 1).fold(0)(_ + _)

    val words: RunnableGraph[ActorRef] = Source.actorRef(Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.fail)
      .via(counts)
      .to(sink)

    val ref = words.run()

    for {
      ln <- scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines.takeWhile(_ != "-1")
    } {
      println("---> Message sent " + ln)
      ref ! ln
    }
    ref ! Success("end")
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    system.terminate()
  }
}
```

It does very simple things: On the application terminal, I input sentences. It extracts words and then keeps maintaining the frequency of each word. And it works as expected. The problem is:

- The Source is an infinite stream. i.e. only when I end the source, does it print the output. Can I refactor the program to always print live stats instead of ending. I understand, this behavior is expected due to `reduce`

A lame way to do is to have a print statement inside `reduce`. But can I do something else, like send live stats post each sentence to another sink (via broadcast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`scan`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#scan) combinator. It will give you the aggregating power of `fold`/`reduce` but it will emit intermediate results.

```
//    .reduce((l, r) => (l._1, l._2 + r._2))
      .scan("" → 0)((l, r) => (l._1, l._2 + r._2))
```

In addition, if you want to send the outputs to a logging `Sink`, you can look into `alsoTo`, which will effectively perform a broadcast to a side `Sink` of choice.